# Getting java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer Error

Tags: java, android

I've been lurking here for answers but I can't seem to find what's wrong with my code. If I convert `positionOfCorrectAnswer` and `getTag` to string then code is working fine but if both are in Integer type I am getting an error `java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer` in the compiler.

```java
public void chooseAnswer(View view)
    {
        int positionOfCorrectAnswer= rand.nextInt(4);

        if(positionOfCorrectAnswer==(Integer)view.getTag())

        {
            score++;
            resultTextView.setText("correct");

        }
        else
            {
                resultTextView.setText("Wrong");

            }
        question++;
        scoreTextView.setText(Integer.toString(score)+"/"+ Integer.toString(question));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Integer.parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) to convert a `String` to an `int`. You cannot simply cast it.

```
if(positionOfCorrectAnswer==Integer.parseInt(view.getTag()))
```